# how to align the EditText to the layout?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-edittext

Hi I have some problems with aligning the EditText in Android.

my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title goes here" />

</LinearLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/middleSection"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/header" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/userRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Username" />

        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userEdit" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/passwordRow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/passwordText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Password" />

        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passordEdit" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxRow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxBlank"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" "/>

        <CheckBox 
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show Password"/>


    </TableRow>



</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

my output looks like this:

```
Username i__i
Password i__I
         chBox Show Password
```

actually, I want to have:

```
Username i__________________i
Password i__________________i
         chBox Show Password
```

I could not figure it out how to align it as I am new to Android(and XML)

thanks

Comment: Better use `GridLayout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `android:ems="10"` to the `EditText` properties in the `XML`. The number 10 is an arbitrary number, and you can increase or decrease it depending on how long you want the `EditText`.

That, or you could just drag it longer to a relative point in the `Graphical Layout` tab of the `XML`.

Answer (score 0):

use `android:stretchColumns="*"` in TableLayout tag that stretch column that you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title goes here" />

</LinearLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/middleSection"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
     >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/userRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Username" />

        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userEdit" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/passwordRow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/passwordText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Password" />

        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passordEdit" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxRow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxBlank"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" "/>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >
        <CheckBox 
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show Password"/>
</LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>



</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: android:stretchColumns="*" stretch all of column of table if you only want stretch column 1 you should use  android:stretchColumns="1"

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will work.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title goes here"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <!--ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" /-->

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/middleSection"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/header" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/userRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >


        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Username" />

        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userEdit" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/passwordRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/passwordText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Password" />

        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passordEdit" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <CheckBox 
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show Password"/>


    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<CheckBox 
                android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/checkBoxText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Show Password"/>
```

put your above code in one parent layout says Linearlayout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
        <CheckBox 
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show Password"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

what happening is you have 2 controls in each table row except last one which hase 3 controls in it so your EditText has its width according to the second control width that is your check box. so putting  CheckBox and TextView in one Linear Layout consider it as a one control (or Layout) and your EditText adjusted according to that.